# "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" Chrome Extension content.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
chrome.tabs.query({
active: true,
lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
// and use that tab to fill in out title and url
var tab = tabs[0];
console.log(tab.url);
alert(tab.url);
 });
```

This is my code. I have added

```
"permissions": [
   "tabs"
],
```

to `manifest.json`

whenever i try to load a web page, instead of it alerting the `url`, it logs the error `"Cannot read property 'query' of undefined"`.

I have no idea why. Please help, thanks

Comment: _"...However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot: Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of: `extension`, `i18n`, `runtime`, `storage`"_ from [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: So I put it in background.js? How do I make it so it alerts the url everytime i visit a page?

Comment: @Andreas This tutorial is wrong: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension

Comment: I don't know, I haven't built an extension yet. That was just the result of a short search...